# How to break page at paragraph level?

Tags: java, itext7

How can I start a new page at paragraph level? I know I can do this at document level, but this would break my formatting.

Perhaps there is function to find the remaining lines on page depending on font and fontsize?

Comment: The correct way would be to have two paragraphs instead of two in this case. How exactly does it break you layout? I think you are trying to solve the problem by creating even bigger one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do this.
But it requires some knowledge about how iText renders its content.

Internally, when a `Paragraph` object is rendered, it uses a `ParagraphRenderer`. Each `ParagraphRenderer` has one or more `LineRenderer` objects as its children. And similarly, each `LineRenderer` has one or more `TextRenderer` objects.

In order to get information about where a paragraph would be split, you can ask the `Paragraph` object to perform layout against a given `LayoutContext` object (which contains the width and height of available space, as well as some other useful information), and get the `LayoutResult` back.

`LayoutResult` will be able to tell you where the `Paragraph was split`.

Try the following piece of code.
`w` denotes the available width
`h` denotes the available height

```
Rectangle layoutRect = new Rectangle(w,h);
LayoutArea layoutArea = new LayoutArea(1,layoutRect);
LayoutContext context = new LayoutContext(layoutArea);

Text layoutText  = new Text(s);
layoutText.setTextRise(0f);
layoutText.setSplitCharacters(new DefaultSplitCharacters());
layoutText.setFont(font);
layoutText.setFontSize(fontSize);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph().add(layoutText);
LayoutResult hwResult = p.createRendererSubTree().layout(context);
```

At that point, use an IDE to inspect the `LayoutResult` object. If the text was split, you should see a `SplitRenderer`, which can give you more information.